# Git access error in VS Code but works in CMD

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am trying to connect my remote Azure DevOps git repo to VS Code so updates can be committed/pushed from the IDE. When I try to synchronize the changes within VS Code or run any commands to the remote repo from the built-in terminal I get the following git error:

```
git pull --tags origin develop
fatal: unable to access 'https://[SITENAME].visualstudio.com/[PROJECTNAME]/_git/[REPONAME]/': error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

I am able to run this pull command from the command line without any problem. Proxy settings are properly configured in .gitconfig as well as environment variables. I have tried going through the Azure extension on VS Code but that results in the same error. At this point I'm planning to just manage the repo through the command line, but if anyone could provide some insight on how to fix this issue with the IDE that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a certificate error.

This bellow solved in my case:

1) In your project folder run `start-ssh-agent`

2) add your id_rsa or whatever name of your private RSA key `password`

3) in the same directory open the cmd or power shell and run `code`

Comment: This is what I did - ran `start-ssh-agent` as you said, then ran `ssh-keygen -f [name for key]` and then entered my password for DevOps. This allowed the push to work from VS Code. Thanks!